# Determine if the second array is the first array shifted to the right by 1

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

The question is to determine if the second array is the first array shifted to the right by 1.
*Examples:*
simonSays([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) ➞ true
simonSays([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 5, 1, 2, 3]) ➞ false

My code is as follows:

```
bool simonSays(std::vector<int> arr1, std::vector<int> arr2) {
    
    for(int i=0; i<arr1.size(); i++)
        if(arr1[i]==arr2[i+1]) 
        return true;
    
    return false;
}
```

However, my code fails on this test case. My output is true but it should actually be false:

```
It(Test4){Assert::That(simonSays({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 3}), Equals(false));}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You are going out of bounds at the last element. You need to wrap around to the front.

Comment: @GaryHoliday I don't think I quite understand, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Can you be more precise as to what you mean by "shifted to the right by 1"?  Your test case seems to be looking for having all of the values adjusted by 1, but the code is checking if values have shifted position.

Comment: Your code ASSUMES that `arr2` has more elements than `arr1`, since it accesses arr2[arr1.size()+1]` in the last iteration of the loop. The failing test case has `arr1.size() == arr2.size()`, so is accessing `arr2[array2.size()]` which gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform an additional check so that you don't access outside the bounds of `arr2`:

```
// You should prefer const references to avoid copying of the vectors in the parameters
bool simonSays(std::vector<int> const& arr1, std::vector<int> const& arr2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.size() && i + 1 < arr2.size(); i++)
        /* The problem with using 'arr[i] == arr2[i + 1]' is that it stops iterating any
           further just after the first instance of finding an equal element in the
           two vectors, so use it's inverse, i.e., 'arr[i] != arr[i + 1]' */
        if(arr1[i] != arr2[i + 1]) 
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Alternatively, you could write the whole function like this with the help of [`std::equal()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) from the C++ Standard Library:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

// ...

bool simonSays(std::vector<int> const& arr1, std::vector<int> const& arr2) {
    return std::equal(std::next(arr2.begin()), arr2.end(), arr1.begin());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I completely understand it now :)

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with my code?

- If any of the comparison match, then you return `true`. Since the first comparison matches in your test case, the result is true.
- You don't check the size of the second array.
- Even if the arrays are of same size, the last iteration will access the second array outside of its bounds and the behaviour of the program will be undefined. This case occurs when none of the comparisons match.